# Regex for Regex validation decimal[19,3]

Tags: regex

I want to validate a decimal number (`decimal[19,3]`). I used this

```
@"[\d]{1,16}|[\d]{1,16}[\.]\d{1,3}"
```

but it didn't work.

Below are valid values:

```
1234567890123456.123
1234567890123456.12
1234567890123456.1 
1234567890123456
1234567
0.0
.1
```

Comment: What about `[0-9]{0,19}|[0-9]{0,19}[.][0-9]{1,3}`?

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to match decimal[19,3], or is it decimal[16,3]?

Comment: You don't have to use any of those square brackets - `\d` already is a character class, and `\.` is an escaped dot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Simplification:**

The `\d` doesn't have to be in `[]`. Use `[]` only when you want to check whether a character is one of multiple characters or character classes.

`.` doesn't need to be escaped inside `[]` - `[\.]` appears to just allow `.`, but allowing `\` to appear in the string in the place of the `.` may be a language dependent possibility (?). Or you can just take it out of the `[]` and keep it escaped.

So we get to:

```
\d{1,16}|\d{1,16}\.\d{1,3}
```

(which can be shortened using the optional / "once or not at all" quantifier (`?`)
     to `\d{1,16}(\.\d{1,3})?`)

**Corrections:**

You probably want to make the second `\d{1,16}` optional, or equivalently simply make it `\d{0,16}`, so something like `.1` is allowed:

```
\d{1,16}|\d{0,16}\.\d{1,3}
```

If something like `1.` should also be allowed, you'll need to add an optional `.` to the first part:

```
\d{1,16}\.?|\d{0,16}\.\d{1,3}
```

---

**Edit:** I was under the impression `[\d]` matches `\` or `d`, but it actually matches the character class `\d` (corrected above).

Comment: The first part needs to be `?`'d as well, see last case of `.1` :)

Comment: @Jerry Indeed, fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `{1,16}?` just use `{0,16}` :-) Also, for the first one you should shorten it to `\d{1,16}(?:\.\d{1,3})?`

Comment: @ParagMeshram [It doesn't with Java](https://ideone.com/GGOx3t). Are you maybe doing a `find` instead of a `matches` in whichever language you tested this?

Comment: @Parag: Yours as well. Of course, you'd have to anchor them; but that's implicit as the OP didn't include them as well

Comment: `\d{1,16}(\.\d{1,3})?` makes this match .123 as 123 which is bad, the dot should be included in the capturing group

Comment: @Bergi & Dukeling - Yup. got it.

Comment: @FRoZeN "match .123 as 123" - I'm not really sure what you mean by this. A match returns yes or no, nothing gets matched "as" something else. Are you talking about doing a `find` instead of a `matches`? (in which case [it will find `.123` as required, not `123`](https://ideone.com/EeSFRK).

Comment: @Bergi - Modified regex. I believe it covers every test case.

Comment: @Dukeling using regexbuddy [it just looked like the regex didnt match](http://bit.ly/13g44O2) the dot before the decimals, but it did match the test data yes. just like "abcdefg 123" would result in a match.

Comment: @FRoZeN Only `\d{1,16}\.?|\d{0,16}\.\d{1,3}` (the last regex in my answer) should be used (or `\d{1,16}|\d{0,16}\.\d{1,3}` if you don't want `1.` to match). The others are intermediate steps to get there.

Comment: @Dukeling [this is the results](http://bit.ly/13gdEAg) i get on your last regex, still seems odd the way the regex only matches some of the data (the image is a per line comparison)

Comment: @FRoZeN [One just needs to swap the two terms around](http://www.debuggex.com/r/IPzjH51MP92JMU-7) (to `\d{0,16}\.\d{1,3}|\d{1,16}\.?`).

Comment: @Dukeling that seems to work, what about .1234567, seems to me that gets matched as two seperate matches aswell, isn't that an issue aswell? this is the reason i introduced the anchor points in my answer, but that ofcourse will not work if the OP is trying to find a match inside lines.

Comment: @FRoZeN That's a little more complicated to deal with. You can possibly add look-around - `(?<![.\d])` at the start and `(?![.\d])` at the end. Note - `^` or `$` will only work if they classify as line start / end rather than string start / end (which is not guaranteed), otherwise you can use something like `^|\r?\n`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31123/discussion-between-frozen-and-dukeling)

Answer (score 2):

This would match your 3 scenarios

```
^(\d{1,16}|(\d{0,16}\.)?\d{1,3})$
```

first part: a 0 to 16 digit number

second: a 0 to 16 digit number with 1 to 3 decimals

third: nothing before a dot and then 1 to 3 decimals

the `^` and `$` are anchorpoints that match start of line and end of line, so if you need to search for numbers inside lines of text, your should remove those.

**Testdata:**

[image]

**Usage in C#**

```
string resultString = null;
try {
    resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, @"\d{1,16}\.?|\d{0,16}\.\d{1,3}").Value;
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

**Slight optimization**

A bit more complicated regex, but a bit more correct would be to have the `?:` notation in the "inner" group, if you are not using it, to make that a non-capture group, like this:

```
^(\d{1,16}|(?:\d{0,16}\.)?\d{1,3})$
```

Comment: That's better, but your regex will still match an empty string `""`.

Answer (score 1):

Following Regex will help you out -

```
@"^(\d{1,16}(\.\d{1,3})?|\.\d{1,3})$"
```

Comment: the empty string would be valid

Comment: @Bergi - input string should be validated with null and empty and throw appropriate exception.

Comment: Yeah, this would be a fine way to do it, but you'll have to mention that :-)

Comment: @Bergi - Thanks. Followed your comment :)

Comment: @Bergi - Modified regex. This pretty much covers every test case :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that

```
(\d{0,16}\.\d{0,3})|(\d{0,16})
```

It work with all your examples.

edit. new version ;)

Comment: This will match `11111111111111111111111111111111`

Comment: That would match a 32-digit long integer

Comment: Now, it will also match a 19-digit long integer.

Comment: I guess he probably needs 2 regular expressions. One for true decimal with "dot" inside and second for int.

Comment: Now it will match the empty string. See @Dukeling's answer for a solution

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
^\d{0,16}(?:\.|$)(?:\d{0,3}|)$
```

match 0 to 16 digits
then match a dot or end of string
and then match 3 more digits

Comment: The empty string would be valid. Also, `\d{0,3}` is already optional